# Redireccionar paginas jsf con parametros

Tags: java, jsf

agradezco de su colaboración, estoy haciendo una pagina `jsf` que realiza una autenticación básica con usuario y contraseña, si la autenticación es correcta redirecciona a otra pagina, sin embargo requiero enviarle dos `String`

este es mi `form` de autenticación

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Usuario: <h:inputText value="#{loginController.username}"/>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Password: <h:inputText value="#{loginController.password}"/>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                   <h:commandButton action="#{loginController.autenticar()}" value="Login"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

y este es el método `autenticar` del ManageBean

```
public String autenticar(){
        this.session = null;
        if(this.session.trim().equals("") || this.session == null){
            return null;
        }else{
            return "albumes";
        }
    }
```

La pagina `albumes` debe recibir dos parametros porque son los utilizados para enviar una `header` en un `ResFul Service`.

Como envio estos dos parametroa a la pagina `albumes`??

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que concatenar `"?faces-redirect=true"` al String con la cadena de redirección, y añadirle tus parámetros. Por ejemplo:

```
return "albumes?faces-redirect=true&usuario="+username+"&password="+password;
```